# MKS : si command to save gui at some location

Tags: mks-integrity

I am working on some desktop based application, which required access to MKS through command line. I am able to understand and run MKS si commands successfully.

Here, I need help in saving "gui" window which opens through MKS si command at some location. For Example:-

Steps:-
After connecting to MKS using si connect command

Use command to view sandbox member history with "gui" option say:-

"si viewhistory --gui --sandbox="sandbox path" --fields=revision memberfile.xml"

Above command will open the MKS UI of Member history.

Here, instead of opening the UI at desktop, I want to save this UI at some location on my desktop say "Libraries\Pictures".

Kindly suggest,

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: do you like something like a screenshot of the UI? `--gui` always will open the GUI application. So you cannot prevent opening the GUI and save its graphics

Comment: Hello Vasilenicursor, Thanks for your reply. Yes I want to take a screenshot of the UI and then want to save it at some location. I didn't find any command to take a screenshot of the GUI and save at some location. kindly suggest if there is any command to save the GUI screenshot instead of opening it.

Comment: MKS cli doesn't have suport for this. But you can use an externat tool, like 'screenshot-cmd' (google search) and use-it to take a screenshot of the GUI. You can't do this without opening the GUI.